# How can I get coin names in Binance

Tags: python-3.x, list, binance

Sorry for my English.
I'm beginner,
I try get coin name in Binance and I can't.
How can i get coin names?
Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
    from binance.client import Client
    import MyAPI
    
    Connect = Client(MyAPI.MyAPI_KEY, MyAPI.MyAPI_SECRET)
    Coins = Connect.get_all_coins_info() 
    Pairs = Coins[::]
    PairNames = Pairs['coin']
    print(PairNames)
```

here is the error i got.

`list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

also i can access one coin name in Binance like this.

```
from binance.client import Client
import MyAPI

Connect = Client(MyAPI.MyAPI_KEY, MyAPI.MyAPI_SECRET)

Coins = Connect.get_all_coins_info() 
Pair = Coins[0]
PairNames = Pair['coin']
print(PairNames)
```

The Outpot `STPT`

Comment: `Pairs` seem to be a list so you can not do `Pairs ['coin']` . This `Pairs ['coin']` operation is performed on dictionaries

Comment: get_all_coins_info () What does it return?

Comment: but i can access one of coin like this
```from binance.client import Client
import MyAPI

Connect = Client(MyAPI.MyAPI_KEY, MyAPI.MyAPI_SECRET)

Coins = Connect.get_all_coins_info() 
Pair = Coins[0]
PairNames = Pair['coin']
print(PairNames)```

The Outpot `STPT`

Comment: get_all_coins_info() return list